# Access value through parent attribute

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, attributes, parent

I am looking to get the value A-1 through xpath based on a passed attribue.

I have passed the index attribute of the unit through php from a previous page and am accessing it by global GET:

```
$value = intval($_GET['index']);
```

the xml:

```
<UNIT index='1'>
     <ID>A-1</ID>
     <MANUFACTURER>testing inc.</MANUFACTURER>
</UNIT>
<UNIT index='2'>
     <ID>A-2</ID>
     <MANUFACTURER>testing inc.</MANUFACTURER>
</UNIT>
```

I'm trying to echo it out using:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('demo.xml',NULL,true);

echo $xml->UNIT[$value]->ID;
```

I know i'm getting the "1" that I need passed through because I echo'd $value to check, but
its giving me the ID of A-2, which would be the xml index number (starting from 0) - not my attribute index number.

Comment: You're not using xpath. That would be something like $xml->xpath(`$path)`;

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML with xpath and PHP: How to access the text value of an attribute of an entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912240/xml-with-xpath-and-php-how-to-access-the-text-value-of-an-attribute-of-an-entry) ***EDIT: this one: [XML with xpath and PHP: How to access the text value of an attribute of an entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992450/simplexml-selecting-elements-which-have-a-certain-attribute-value)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) method to query for the specific `UNIT` that you want with an XPath query like `//UNIT[@index=2]`.

```
$value = intval($_GET['index']);
$xml   = new SimpleXMLElement('demo.xml',NULL,true);
$units = $xml->xpath("//UNIT[@index=$value]"); // xpath returns an array
if (isset($units[0])) {
    echo $units[0]->ID;
} else {
    echo "No unit with index $value";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

`//UNIT[@index=$value]/ID`