# Accessing totalResults property from google contacts returned xml

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to access 'totalResults' from following xml which was returned by google(contacts)

```html
 <generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>29</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this PHP tutorial from the PHP docs on [how to access attributes in XML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php):

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <foo name="one" game="lonely">1</foo>
</a>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->foo[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
name="one"
game="lonely"
```

Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912240/xml-with-xpath-and-php-how-to-access-the-text-value-of-an-attribute-of-an-entry) for additional reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = '<generator version="1.0" uri="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds">Contacts</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>29</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>'

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xml->openSearch->totalResults;
```

Comment: Sorry , it didn't work.  If you want to see the [full original xml file](http://www.unifiedvu.com/xerotest/simple.xml)